# Idiom for ifelse-style recoding for multiple categories

Tags: r, r-factor, recode

I run across this often enough that I figure there has to be a good idiom for it.  Suppose I have a data.frame with a bunch of attributes, including "product."  I also have a key which translates products to brand + size.  Product codes 1-3 are Tylenol, 4-6 are Advil, 7-9 are Bayer, 10-12 are Generic.

What's the fastest (in terms of human time) way to code this up?

I tend to use nested `ifelse`'s if there are 3 or fewer categories, and type out the data table and merge it in if there are more than 3.  Any better ideas?  Stata has a [`recode` command](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?recode) that is pretty nifty for this sort of thing, although I believe it promotes data-code intermixing a little too much.

```
dat <- structure(list(product = c(11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 11L, 5L, 
7L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 8L)), .Names = "product", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Lots of SO creativity on display here.  Going to have a hard time picking an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One could use a list as an associative array to define the `brand -> product code` mapping, i.e.:

```
brands <- list(Tylenol=1:3, Advil=4:6, Bayer=7:9, Generic=10:12)
```

Once you have this, you can then either invert this to create a `product code -> brand` list (could take a lot of memory), or just use a search function:

```
find.key <- function(x, li, default=NA) {
    ret <- rep.int(default, length(x))
    for (key in names(li)) {
        ret[x %in% li[[key]]] <- key
    }
    return(ret)
}
```

I'm sure there are better ways of writing this function (the `for` loop is annoying me!), but at least it is vectorised, so it only requires a single pass through the list.

Using it would be something like:

```
> dat$brand <- find.key(dat$product, brands)
> dat
   product   brand
1       11 Generic
2       11 Generic
3        9   Bayer
4        9   Bayer
5        6   Advil
6        1 Tylenol
7       11 Generic
8        5   Advil
9        7   Bayer
10      11 Generic
11       5   Advil
12      11 Generic
13       4   Advil
14       3 Tylenol
15      10 Generic
16       7   Bayer
17      10 Generic
18       5   Advil
19       9   Bayer
20       8   Bayer
```

The `recode` and `levels<-` solutions are very nice, but they are also significantly slower than this one (and once you have `find.key` this is easier-for-humans than `recode` and on par with the `levels<-`):

```
> microbenchmark(
     recode=recode(dat$product,recodes="1:3='Tylenol';4:6='Advil';7:9='Bayer';10:12='Generic'"), 
     find.key=find.key(dat$product, brands),
     levels=`levels<-`(factor(dat$product),brands))
Unit: microseconds
      expr      min        lq    median        uq      max
1 find.key   64.325   69.9815   76.8950   83.8445  221.748
2   levels  240.535  248.1470  274.7565  306.8490 1477.707
3   recode 1636.039 1683.4275 1730.8170 1855.8320 3095.938
```

(I can't get the `switch` version to benchmark properly, but it appears to be faster than all of the above, although it is even worse-for-humans than the `recode` solution.)

Comment: Fun solution, but definitely doesn't pass the faster-for-humans muster!

Comment: Why not? `find.key` is a generic function you can just copy paste into your code and use.

Comment: Newer version looks very easy to use.  This version didn't: `cbind(dat,dat$brand brand=find<- find.key(dat$product, brands))`.  But now that I actually look at it it's not complicated either.  Morning stupidity :-)

Comment: Very nice response and very fast.  I like it a lot. +1

Comment: @gsk3, yeah, I had trouble working out how to vectorise `find.key` and so didn't think how to do the last step very much. Evening mindblank :)

Comment: Here's a version without a `for` loop; unsure if it would be any faster, but here it is anyway: `find.key2 <- function(x, li) { cut(match(x, unlist(li)), c(0, cumsum(sapply(li, length))), labels=names(li)) }`

Comment: I still love this function, but I just noticed it replaces anything not in the `li` list with `NA`.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, that's what the `default` argument controls: `find.key(c(1,13), brands, default="missing")` => `[1] "Tylenol" "missing"`

Comment: @dbaupp I was thinking something like `default=dat$product` and it would instead insert the particular product code that didn't have a label.  But now that I think about it it's probably better to return `NA` and fill in the missings with the codes after the fact.

Answer (score 19):

You could convert your variable to a factor and change its levels by `levels<-` function. In one command it could be like:

```
`levels<-`(
    factor(dat$product),
    list(Tylenol=1:3, Advil=4:6, Bayer=7:9, Generic=10:12)
)
```

In steps:

```
brands <- factor(dat$product)
levels(brands) <- list(Tylenol=1:3, Advil=4:6, Bayer=7:9, Generic=10:12)
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest way, even though your first call to `levels<-` will probably confuse a lot of people. :)

Comment: Nice shortcut! I found its explanation here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10449366/1460352)

Answer (score 13):

I like the `recode` function in the `car` package:

```
library(car)

dat$brand <- recode(dat$product,
  recodes="1:3='Tylenol';4:6='Advil';7:9='Bayer';10:12='Generic'")

# > dat
#    product   brand
# 1       11 Generic
# 2       11 Generic
# 3        9   Bayer
# 4        9   Bayer
# 5        6   Advil
# 6        1 Tylenol
# 7       11 Generic
# 8        5   Advil
# 9        7   Bayer
# 10      11 Generic
# 11       5   Advil
# 12      11 Generic
# 13       4   Advil
# 14       3 Tylenol
# 15      10 Generic
# 16       7   Bayer
# 17      10 Generic
# 18       5   Advil
# 19       9   Bayer
# 20       8   Bayer
```

Comment: the only problem with `recode` is that it works by processing strings, so if your codes/data happen to have semicolons and = signs in them it's a big headache ...

Answer (score 8):

I often use the technique below:

```
key <- c()
key[1:3] <- "Tylenol"
key[4:6] <- "Advil"
key[7:9] <- "Bayer"
key[10:12] <- "Generic"
```

Then,

```
> key[dat$product]
 [1] "Generic" "Generic" "Bayer"   "Bayer"   "Advil"   "Tylenol" "Generic" "Advil"   "Bayer"   "Generic"
[11] "Advil"   "Generic" "Advil"   "Tylenol" "Generic" "Bayer"   "Generic" "Advil"   "Bayer"   "Bayer"
```

Answer (score 7):

The "database approach" is to keep a separate table (a data.frame) for your product keys definitions. It makes even more sense since you say your product keys translate into not only a brand, but also a size:

```
product.keys <- read.table(textConnection("

product brand   size
1       Tylenol small
2       Tylenol medium
3       Tylenol large
4       Advil   small
5       Advil   medium
6       Advil   large
7       Bayer   small
8       Bayer   medium
9       Bayer   large
10      Generic small
11      Generic medium
12      Generic large

"), header = TRUE)
```

Then, you can join your data using `merge`:

```
merge(dat, product.keys, by = "product")
#    product   brand   size
# 1        1 Tylenol  small
# 2        3 Tylenol  large
# 3        4   Advil  small
# 4        5   Advil medium
# 5        5   Advil medium
# 6        5   Advil medium
# 7        6   Advil  large
# 8        7   Bayer  small
# 9        7   Bayer  small
# 10       8   Bayer medium
# 11       9   Bayer  large
# 12       9   Bayer  large
# 13       9   Bayer  large
# 14      10 Generic  small
# 15      10 Generic  small
# 16      11 Generic medium
# 17      11 Generic medium
# 18      11 Generic medium
# 19      11 Generic medium
# 20      11 Generic medium
```

As you notice, the order of the rows is not preserved by `merge`. If this is a problem, the `plyr` package has a `join` function that does preserve the order:

```
library(plyr)
join(dat, product.keys, by = "product")
#    product   brand   size
# 1       11 Generic medium
# 2       11 Generic medium
# 3        9   Bayer  large
# 4        9   Bayer  large
# 5        6   Advil  large
# 6        1 Tylenol  small
# 7       11 Generic medium
# 8        5   Advil medium
# 9        7   Bayer  small
# 10      11 Generic medium
# 11       5   Advil medium
# 12      11 Generic medium
# 13       4   Advil  small
# 14       3 Tylenol  large
# 15      10 Generic  small
# 16       7   Bayer  small
# 17      10 Generic  small
# 18       5   Advil medium
# 19       9   Bayer  large
# 20       8   Bayer medium
```

Finally, if your tables are large and speed is an issue, consider using data.tables (from the `data.table` package) instead of data.frames.

Comment: Isn't there a `,sort=FALSE` option for merge that preserves the order of the rows?

Answer (score 6):

This  one takes some typing but if you really do have a huge data set this may be the way to go.  Bryangoodrich and Dason at talkstats.com taught me this one.  It's using a hash table or creating a environment that contains a look up table.  I actually keep this one on my .Rprofile (the hash function that is) for dictionary type look ups.

I replicated your data 1000 times to make it a bit larger.

```
#################################################
# THE HASH FUNCTION (CREATES A ENW ENVIRONMENT) #
#################################################
hash <- function(x, type = "character") {
    e <- new.env(hash = TRUE, size = nrow(x), parent = emptyenv())
    char <- function(col) assign(col[1], as.character(col[2]), envir = e)
    num <- function(col) assign(col[1], as.numeric(col[2]), envir = e)
    FUN <- if(type=="character") char else num
    apply(x, 1, FUN)
    return(e)
}
###################################
# YOUR DATA REPLICATED 1000 TIMES #
###################################
dat <- dat <- structure(list(product = c(11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 11L, 5L, 
    7L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 8L)), .Names = "product", row.names = c(NA, 
    -20L), class = "data.frame")
dat <- dat[rep(seq_len(nrow(dat)), 1000), , drop=FALSE]
rownames(dat) <-NULL
dat
#########################
# CREATE A LOOKUP TABLE #
#########################
med.lookup <- data.frame(val=as.character(1:12), 
    med=rep(c('Tylenol', 'Advil', 'Bayer', 'Generic'), each=3))  

########################################
# USE hash TO CREATE A ENW ENVIRONMENT #
########################################  
meds <- hash(med.lookup)  

##############################
# CREATE A RECODING FUNCTION #
##############################          
recoder <- function(x){
    x <- as.character(x) #turn the numbers to character
    rc <- function(x){
       if(exists(x, env = meds))get(x, e = meds) else NA 
    }  
    sapply(x, rc, USE.NAMES = FALSE) 
}
#############
# HASH AWAY #
#############
recoder(dat[, 1])
```

In this case hashing is slow but if you have more levels to recode then it will increase in speed over others.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat more readable than nested `ifelse`'s:

```
unlist(lapply(as.character(dat$product), switch,
              `1`=,`2`=,`3`='tylenol',
              `4`=,`5`=,`6`='advil',
              `7`=,`8`=,`9`='bayer',
              `10`=,`11`=,`12`='generic'))
```

Caveat: not very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use this function:

```
recoder <- function (x, from = c(), to = c()) {
  missing.levels <- unique(x)
  missing.levels <- missing.levels[!missing.levels %in% from]
  if (length(missing.levels) > 0) {
    from <- append(x = from, values = missing.levels)
    to <- append(x = to, values = missing.levels)
  }
  to[match(x, from)]
}
```

As in:

```
recoder(x = dat$product, from = 1:12, to = c(rep("Product1", 3), rep("Product2", 3), rep("Product3", 3), rep("Product4", 3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have codes in sequential groups like in the example, this may `cut` the mustard:

```
cut(dat$product,seq(0,12,by=3),labels=c("Tylenol","Advil","Bayer","Generic"))
 [1] Generic Generic Bayer   Bayer   Advil   Tylenol Generic Advil   Bayer  
[10] Generic Advil   Generic Advil   Tylenol Generic Bayer   Generic Advil  
[19] Bayer   Bayer  
Levels: Tylenol Advil Bayer Generic
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also `arules:discretize`, but I like it less because it makes you separate the labels from the range of values:

```
library(arules)
discretize( dat$product, method = "fixed", categories = c( 1,3,6,9,12 ), labels = c("Tylenol","Advil","Bayer","Generic") )

[1] Generic Generic Generic Generic Bayer   Tylenol Generic Advil   Bayer   Generic Advil   Generic Advil   Advil   Generic Bayer   Generic Advil   Generic Bayer  
Levels: Tylenol Advil Bayer Generic
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness (and probably fastest and simplest solution) one can create and named vector and use it for lookup.
Credit: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#applications

```
product.code <- c(1='Tylenol', 2='Tylenol', 3='Tylenon', 4='Advil', 5 ='Advil', 6='Advil', 7='Bayer', 8='Bayer', 9='Bayer', 10='Generic', 11='Generic', 12='Generic')
```

To get the output

```
$unname(product.code[dat$product])
```

Bench-marking for speed with the top solutions

```
$microbenchmark(
 named_vector = unname(product.code[dat$product]), 
 find.key = find.key(dat$product, brands),
 levels = `levels<-`(factor(dat$product),brands))
Unit: microseconds
         expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
 named_vector  11.777  20.4810  26.12832  23.0410  28.1610 207.360   100
     find.key  34.305  55.8090  58.75804  59.1370  65.5370 130.049   100
       levels 143.361 224.7685 234.02545 247.5525 255.7445 338.944   100
```

This solution is very similar to @kohske's solution but would work for non-numerical lookup.

Comment: You need to call `unname(product.code[as.character(dat$product]))` in order for this to make sense. Then it becomes quite a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another version, that would work in this case:

```
c("Tylenol","Advil","Bayer","Generic")[(dat$product %/% 3.1) + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Canonical tidyverse method to update some values of a vector from a look-up table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67081496/canonical-tidyverse-method-to-update-some-values-of-a-vector-from-a-look-up-tabl)

Based on the code from above question, the question has a good solution by look-up table and left_join in tidyverse style.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

First, we should set a look-up table. You could set the look-up table in a csv file for shortest human time.

```
lookup <- tribble(
  ~brand, ~code, ~size,
  "Tylenol", 1, "small",
  "Tylenol", 2, "medium",
  "Tylenol", 3, "large",
  "Advil", 4, "small",
  "Advil", 5, "medium",
  "Advil", 6, "large",
  "Bayer", 7, "small",
  "Bayer", 8, "medium",
  "Bayer", 9, "large",
  "Generic", 10, "small",
  "Generic", 11, "medium",
  "Generic", 12, "large"
)
```

Then, we can create new variables using the lookup table.

```
newdat <- dat %>% 
  left_join(lookup, by = c("product" = "code")) %>%
  select(-product)
```

Although this answer may be outdated, since it was the first question I encountered when searching for such answer, and it took me hours to search for an tidy answer, I'm sure my answer made some sense.