# Coding string to numeric in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data set in R which has a column with 0-1 month, 8-9 month, etc. I want to code this column as a numeric variable with number of months. For example, instead of 8-9 month, put just 9.
Thanks for help and comments.

Comment: Also check out the answers to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431403/idiom-for-ifelse-style-recoding-for-multiple-categories)

Answer (score 4):

In one swoop

```
a <- c("0-1 month", "8-9 months")
as.integer(gsub("^[[:digit:]]+-([[:digit:]]+) month[s]*", "\\1", a))
```

Comment: I edited the input, because it was trying to convert "0-1" and "8-9" to integer.

Comment: If you don't have "month(s)" as part of the character string, then you can get rid of the ` month[s]*` part of the line that I give.

Answer (score 2):

With the `recode` function from the `car` package.  It's not as succinct as the `gsub` solution, but it's more flexible and it may be easier to read:

```
library(car)
a <- c("0-1 month", "8-9 months")
recode(a, '"0-1 month" = 1; "8-9 months" = 2')
```