# coding multiple levels with single label with factor

Tags: r

I have language data containing over 200 languages with some missing values coded as '' (0 length characters).

I would like to compress this using `factor` to code main languages, and all others as 'other language' while the '' is coded as '(missing)' showing up at the end of the string.

My plan is this:

```
lanfmt <- list(
  lev = c(prime <- c('English', 'Russian', 'Urdu'), diff <- setdiff(levels(lan), c(prime, '')), ''),
  lab = c(prime, diff, '')
)

table(factor(lan, lanfmt$levels, lanfmt$labels)
```

but R doesn't like many-to-one formats of factors. How do I aggregate into a single category?

EDIT:

I decided a good solution, using `lanfmt` as described above is the following:

`table(lanfmt$lab[match(lang, lanfmt$lev)])`

It's not as elegant, but it works in a pinch.

Comment: Also have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10431403). Although the OP has to do with recoding integer values to character, many (all?) of the approaches will work for your case as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should convert your factors to character, edit them and then order them. Maybe something like this would help (`lan` being the language vector of your list / data frame):

```
lan <- c("English", "Russian", "Urdu", "", "Indonesian")
lan <- factor(lan)
prime <- c("English", "Russian", "Urdu", "missing")
missing <- ""

lan <- as.character(lan)
lan[lan %in% missing] <- "missing"

lan[!lan %in% prime] <- "other language"
lan <- factor(lan)
lan
[1] English        Russian        Urdu           missing       
[5] other language
Levels: English missing other language Russian Urdu
```

After that you can order your languages

```
order <- c("English", "Russian", "Urdu", "other language", "missing")
lan <- ordered(lan, order)
dt <- data.frame(lan, stuff=rnorm(5,4,1))
dt[with(dt, order(lan)),]

             lan    stuff
1        English 4.212460
2        Russian 3.681616
3           Urdu 3.409838
5 other language 3.304108
4        missing 3.938468
```

Comment: This isn't what I wanted but it did give me the idea. Thanks!