# generate labels for variables in R

Tags: r, label

I'm searching for a better/faster way than this one to generate labels for a variable :

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(0,7,1,10,2,4,3,5,10,1,7,8,3,2))
pick <- c(0,1,2,3,10)
df[sapply(df$a,function(x) !(x %in% pick)),"a"] <- "a"
df[sapply(df$a,function(x) x==0),"a"] <- "b"
df[sapply(df$a,function(x) x==1 | x==2 | x==3),"a"] <- "c"
df[sapply(df$a,function(x) x==10),"a"] <- "d"

df$a
[1] "b" "a" "c" "d" "c" "a" "c" "a" "d" "c" "a" "a" "c" "c"
```

For simplicity, I just have one variable in this example, of course there are more variables in my dataset but I just want to change a specific one.

Comment: Related, perhaps helpful, but not necessarily duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10431403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `sapply`:

```
df$a[!df$a %in% pick] <- "a"
df$a[df$a==0] <- "b"
df$a[df$a %in% 1:3] <- "c"
df$a[df$a==10] <- "d"
```

You could also produce the same result with factors:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(0,7,1,10,2,4,3,5,10,1,7,8,3,2))

# the above method
a <- df$a
a[!df$a %in% pick] <- "a"
a[df$a==0] <- "b"
a[df$a %in% 1:3] <- "c"
a[df$a==10] <- "d"

# one way that gives a warning
b1 <- factor(df$a, levels=0:10, labels=c("b",rep("c",3),rep("a",6),"d"))

# another way that won't give a warning
b2 <- factor(df$a)
levels(b2) <- c("b",rep("c",3),rep("a",4),"d")
b2 <- as.character(b2)

# a third strategy using `library(car)`
b3 <- car::recode(df$a,"0='b';1:3='c';10='d';else='a'")

# check that all strategies are the same
all.equal(a,as.character(b1))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(as.character(b1),as.character(b2))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(as.character(b1),as.character(b3))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider `mapvalues` or `revalue` in `plyr`, particularly if you're dealing with more labels:

```
df$a <- mapvalues(df$a, c(0, 1, 2, 3, 10), c("b", "c", "c", "c", "d"))
df$a[! df$a %in% c("b", "c", "d")] <- "a" # The !pick values
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another fairly straightforward solution:

```
names(pick) <- c("b", "c", "c", "c", "d")
x <- names(pick[match(df$a, pick)])
x[is.na(x)] <- "a"
x
# [1] "b" "a" "c" "d" "c" "a" "c" "a" "d" "c" "a" "a" "c" "c"
```

It is even more straightforward if you include an `NA` in your "pick" object.

```
pick <- c(NA, 0, 1, 2, 3, 10)
names(pick) <- c("a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d")
names(pick[match(df$a, pick, nomatch = 1)])
# [1] "b" "a" "c" "d" "c" "a" "c" "a" "d" "c" "a" "a" "c" "c"
```

If you use this second alternative, note that `nomatch` takes an integer value of the position of what you're matching agains. Here, `nomatch` maps to "NA" which is in the first position in your "pick" vector. If the "NA" were in the last position, you would enter it as `nomatch = 6` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ifelse` function.

```
with(df,ifelse(a==0,"b",ifelse(a %in% c(1,2,3),"c",ifelse(a==10,"d","a"))))
 [1] "b" "a" "c" "d" "c" "a" "c" "a" "d" "c" "a" "a" "c" "c"
```