# Applying a function and assigning multiple variables in a single call in R

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, mapply

Some sample R code to consider:

```
df = data.frame(x=letters[1:4], y=letters[5:8])

find.key <- function(x, li, default=NA) {
  ret <- rep.int(default, length(x))
  for (key in names(li)) {
    ret[x %in% li[[key]]] <- key
  }
  return(ret)
}

x2 = list("Alpha" = "a", 
          "Beta"  = "b", 
          "Other" = c("c","d"))

y2 = list("Epi"    = "e", 
          "OtherY" = c("f", "g", "h"))

# This is the code in question, imagine many variables and calls to find.key()
df$NewX2 = find.key(df$x, x2)
df$Newy2 = find.key(df$y, y2)

# df
#   x y NewX2  Newy2
# 1 a e Alpha    Epi
# 2 b f  Beta OtherY
# 3 c g Other OtherY
# 4 d h Other OtherY
```

So the gist of this is I would like to add new variables (NewX2, Newy2) based on a lookup tables (associative arrays/list) via the [find.key function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431403/idiom-for-ifelse-style-recoding-for-multiple-categories).

Is there some way to keep my code DRY? specifically here:

```
df$NewX2 = find.key(df$x, x2)
df$Newy2 = find.key(df$y, y2)
```

I'm not sure `sapply` or `lapply` could help?  Or perhaps something like `%=%` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519790/assign-multiple-new-variables-in-a-single-line-in-r).

I'd like to something like this...(hopefully this makes sense):

```
c(df$NewX2, df$Newy2) = find.key(c(df$x, df$y), c(x2, y2))
```

Comment: How about `df$New <- mapply(find.key, list(df$x, df$y), list(x2, y2))`?

Comment: Also, when recoding, it's easier to have the levels of your `x2/y2` tables flipped. For example: `x2 <- c("a"="Alpha", "b"="Beta", "c"="Other", "d"="Other"); df$newx <-x2[as.character(df$x)]` Then you don't need the find.keys function.

Comment: @MrFlick I understand what you're saying, but imagine a larger lookup table where I might be repeating "other" many times. This is why the list format may be preferable.

Comment: If memory usage is your concern, that makes sense. However doing the actual transformation via indexing as I've written it should be much faster. But that would require testing to confirm. But whatever is easier for you to maintain is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[` extraction for the lefthand-side data.frame rather than `$` extraction:

```
df[,c('NewX2','NewY2')] <- mapply(find.key, 
                                  list(df$x, df$y), 
                                  list(x2, y2), 
                                  SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# df
#   x y NewX2  NewY2
# 1 a e Alpha    Epi
# 2 b f  Beta OtherY
# 3 c g Other OtherY
# 4 d h Other OtherY
```

Or, if you don't like writing `mapply` you can use `Vectorize`, which will create an `mapply`-based function for you to obtain the same result:

```
find.keys <- Vectorize(find.key, c("x","li"), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
df[,c('NewX2','NewY2')] <- find.keys(list(df$x, df$y), list(x2, y2))
df
#   x y NewX2  NewY2
# 1 a e Alpha    Epi
# 2 b f  Beta OtherY
# 3 c g Other OtherY
# 4 d h Other OtherY
```

Comment: People don't use `Vectorize` enough, I don't think.  I love it.  I've created vectorized versions of virtually all non-primitives.  +1