# Set factor levels using ifelse statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement, r-factor

I am trying to use the levels argument for 4 different ifelse scenarios.  However, R isn't recognizing 'levels' as an argument. I tried changing the parenthesis to different locations but still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
cgrp <- as.factor(ifelse(zperform$RISK >= 720,4,  
                       ifelse(zperform$RISK < 720 & zperform$RISK >= 660,3,  
                              ifelse(zperform$RISK < 660 & zperform$RISK >= 659,2,1
                                    ))), levels = letters)
```

Comment: Hi @user3067851, it seems I incorrectly assumed your factors tag referred to Factor programming language. Please correct your title in that case.

Comment: `as.factor()` doesn't have a `levels=` parameter, but `factor()` does; use that instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Idiom for ifelse-style recoding for multiple categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431403/idiom-for-ifelse-style-recoding-for-multiple-categories)