# Is it possible to make a list with a wildcard index in R? [with minimal example now]

Tags: r

Is it possible to construct a list in R which has indices `'a','b','c'` but if you try to access it by *any* other index then it gives a specific value rather than an error?

I'm trying to use this to replace a bunch of nested `ifelse`'s and I need to do deal with the final else part.

[edit]

Here's the code I'm trying to replace

```
All_LDZ$GasRegion<- ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='EA','East Anglia',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='EM','East Midlands',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='NE','North East England',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='NO','North England',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='NT','North Thames Area',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='NW','North West England',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='SC','Scotland',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='SE','South East England',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='SO','Southampton Area',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='SW','South West England',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='WM','West Midland',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='WN','North Wales',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='WS','South Wales', NA)))))))))))))
```

and I want something like

```
descriptiveRegionName <- list('EA'="East Anglia",
                            'EM'="East Midlands",
                            'NE'='North East England',
                            'NO'='North England',
                            'NT'='North Thames Area',
                            'NW'='North West England',
                            'SC'='Scotland',
                            'SE'='South East England',
                            'SO'='Southampton Area',
                            'SW'='South West England',
                            'WM'='West Midland',
                            'WN'='North Wales',
                            'WS'='South Wales',
                            ELSE = NA)
```

Note the ELSE index I made up.

[edit]

This question has been marked as a possible duplicate but I don't see how it's a direct duplicate.

Comment: No, just do it manually after the fact. A specific example might help if you need more explanation.

Comment: using this example `l <- list(a = 1, b = 2)`, accessing 'c' `l[['c']]` returns `NULL`, not an error, so I'm not clear what you mean. Also what "specific value" do you want it to return. but `l[[3]]` would be an error I guess. what about `?tryCatch`

Comment: `mydf <- stack(descriptiveRegionName)` and merge it

Comment: @rawr Thanks. That's good enough.

Comment: I think `?match` is the right way to go here.

Comment: @rawr Do I have to use `lapply`?

Comment: @BenBolker Would I have to use `lapply`?

Comment: @NaN I misunderstood your input. `switch` is used for length 1 vectors. you should use @benbolker's solution. or usually for problems like this I used a named vector and do the matching with a key such as  `key <- c(EA="East Anglia", EM="East Midlands"); x <- c('EM','EM','EX'); unname(key[x])`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Idiom for ifelse-style recoding for multiple categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431403/idiom-for-ifelse-style-recoding-for-multiple-categories)

Comment: @rawr Why is it a duplicate?

Comment: @BenBolker Your suggestion worked. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: @NaN you can go ahead and undelete yours ...

Comment: @rawr, the dupe you suggest is slightly more general (many-to-one; this is one-to-one, so `match()` suffices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ben Bolker suggested

```
All_LDZ$GasRegion<- match(All_LDZ$LDZ,
                      list('EA'='East Anglia',
                        'EM'='East Midlands',
                        'NE'='North East England',
                        'NO'='North England',
                        'NT'='North Thames Area',
                        'NW'='North West England',
                        'SC'='Scotland',
                        'SE'='South East England',
                        'SO'='Southampton Area',
                        'SW'='South West England',
                        'WM'='West Midland',
                        'WN'='North Wales',
                        'WS'='South Wales'),
                      nomatch = NA)
```

can replace

```
All_LDZ$GasRegion<- ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='EA','East Anglia',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='EM','East Midlands',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='NE','North East England',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='NO','North England',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='NT','North Thames Area',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='NW','North West England',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='SC','Scotland',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='SE','South East England',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='SO','Southampton Area',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='SW','South West England',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='WM','West Midland',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='WN','North Wales',
                    ifelse(All_LDZ$LDZ=='WS','South Wales', NA)))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a join be a more maintainable and efficient approach to this task?

The code for that would look like:

```
All_LDZ_decoded <- merge(All_LDZ, GasRegionAbbrevTable)
```

If you named the columns consistently between the tables*, your work is done. If not, then here will help guide the key specifications: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1300618/5088194 or here:https://mkmanu.wordpress.com/2016/04/08/working-with-data-frames-in-r-joins-and-merging/
Though I personally prefer the economy of the [dplyr syntax](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/two-table.html):

Transforming the decoding to a join operation means that we could keep your Abbreviation Table in .csv (from where it might possibly have originated and in which format it would be very easy to modify and manage into the future); we may also continue to use that transportable table in more 'object'-like fashion with other future work, too.

*(and you have normalized your abbrev. table - i.e.: removed duplicates in rows and columns [as in your example])